# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: UnrecognizedPropertyException and Unrecognized field

Tags: json, data-binding

I am new to JSON and I am trying to apply the simplest JSON concept from:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind

It is straight forward and very easy to follow. The explanation makes sense.
The POJO is clean and doesn't have much.
The mapper should do the job but it isn't.

so I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyValue value = objectMapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"Bob\", \"age\":13}", MyValue.class);
    System.out.println("- value.getName = ["+value.getName()+"] ");
    System.out.println("- value.getAge = ["+value.getAge()+"] ");           
} // main()


public class MyValue {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Constructor
    public MyValue() {
    }

} // MyValue Class
```

when I run it, it generates the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.csc.cloud.cp.service.solarwinds.orion.impl.SolarWindsOrionServiceImpl$MyValue]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: {"name":"Bob", "age":13}; line: 1, column: 2]
```

even though I have my default MyValue() constructor in there.

So when I add the following Annotation to the MyValue Class:

```
// Constructor
@JsonCreator 
    public MyValue() {
}
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "name" (class com.csc.cloud.cp.service.solarwinds.orion.impl.SolarWindsOrionServiceImpl), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: {"name":"Bob", "age":13}; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.csc.cloud.cp.service.solarwinds.orion.impl.SolarWindsOrionServiceImpl["name"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
```

I am pulling my hair. Please HELP !!!

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me where have you written the main method? Also show your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

**Solution one**

You can just add annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to your `MyValue` class.

**Solution two**

Add to the configuration `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);` so that the `objectMapper` does not fail on unknown properties.

Comment: Should be great if you can explain further the differences between the two solutions you are providing.